# Android Program Crashing but no Obvious Error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

I've pasted some of my code below.  I'm trying to get this button to activate the calculation below and place the result in an EditText view.  I find no errors listed in the program, but it crashes on my Android phone when I press the button (calcbutton).

I'm wondering if there's a problem with my BigDecimal calculations, but I don't know why there isn't an error reported.

```
public String massVal;
public String volVal;
public String volunitdes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sfp);

//declare ListView
    final ListView mass;

//get ListView object from xml
    mass = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mass);

//defined array values to show in ListView
    String[] masslv = new String[]{"g", "mg", "µg", "mol", "mmol", "µmol"};

//define new Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> massAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, masslv);

//assign Adapter to ListView
    mass.setAdapter(massAdapter);

//ListView Item Click Listener
    mass.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //ListView Clicked item index
        int itemPosition = position;
        //ListView Clicked item value
        String massVal = (String) mass.getItemAtPosition(position);

        //declare EditText for mass and place clicked value (String massVal) into box
            EditText masstext;
            masstext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.masstext);
            masstext.setText(massVal);
        }});



//button for final calculation
Button calcbutton;
calcbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcbutton);

calcbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v) {
  //declare all manual number entries as EditText, then String, then BigDecimal
  EditText CONCdes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CONCdes);
  EditText voldes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.voldes);
  EditText MWbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MWbox);

  String CONCVAL = CONCdes.getText().toString();
  String VOLDES = voldes.getText().toString();
  String MW = MWbox.getText().toString();

  BigDecimal CONCVALbd = new BigDecimal(CONCVAL).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  BigDecimal VOLDESbd = new BigDecimal(VOLDES).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  BigDecimal MWbd = new BigDecimal(MW).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

  //default calculation assumes ug/ml, ml vol units to measure, and mg units to weigh

  BigDecimal FINPOWDMEAS;
  FINPOWDMEAS = VOLDESbd.multiply(CONCVALbd).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

  if (massVal.equals("g"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = FINPOWDMEAS.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);}

  if (massVal.equals("mg"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = FINPOWDMEAS.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));}

  if (massVal.equals("mol"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = VOLDESbd.multiply(CONCVALbd).multiply(MWbd).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);}

  if (massVal.equals("mmol"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = (VOLDESbd.multiply(CONCVALbd).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000))).multiply(MWbd).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

  if (massVal.equals("µmol"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = (VOLDESbd.multiply(CONCVALbd).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000000))).multiply(MWbd).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);}

  if (volVal.equals("L"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = FINPOWDMEAS.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);}

  if (volVal.equals("dL"))
    {FINPOWDMEAS = FINPOWDMEAS.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);}

  if (volVal.equals("µL")){FINPOWDMEAS = FINPOWDMEAS.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);}

  //final calculation value to string
  EditText FINPOWDMEASURE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FINPOWDMEASURE);
  String FINALPOWDERMEASURE = FINPOWDMEAS.toString();
  FINPOWDMEASURE.setText(FINALPOWDERMEASURE);}});
```

Exception:

```
Process: vanwert.sdb, PID: 907
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at vanwert.sdb.SFP$4.onClick(SFP.java:134)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If your app crashes, there's definitely some information in the LogCat. Hard to say what the exact problem is without that, but I can see a few cases where you might have `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I added some information from the LogCat, but a lot of the info. seemed to be streaming before I started the program and also after I disconnected the phone (after the crash).  I tried to isolate the errors here in the log.  I'm new to programming. Isn't a null pointer exception supposed to occur only when a piece of data is missing that the program is trying to retrieve?  I've entered numbers into all the appropriate EditText boxes before pressing the button, so I'm confused.

Comment: What line of code is `SFP.java:134`? Aka. what code is on line `134` in `SFP.java`?

Comment: The very first "if" statement

Comment: Where do you assign `massVal`? `NullPointerException` at that line means `massVal.equals("g")` is being resolved to `null.equals("g")`, which you can't do.

Comment: I declared massVal in a different OnClickListener (not shown here), and also declared it as a global variable at the very top (not shown here).  My confusion is that I want to use the massVal from a different OnClickListener method, so I thought I could just declare it as public at the very beginning of this SFP.java code, and then use it in two different places.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  I just simply want to get that string (massVal) from a different EditText (in a different OnClickListener method) and use it in this method shown here.

Comment: There's a difference between _declaring_ it, like `private String massVal;`, and _assigning_ it, `massVal = "myString"`. You haven't _assigned_ it by the time it reaches that if, so it retains a value of `null`. Keep in mind that the anonymous `OnClickListener` that you created for this has a different scope than the other `OnClickListener` that you haven't shown.

Comment: Okay, I've pasted the relevant code now.  At the top you can see where I declared massVal, and then assigned it within the OnItemClickListener.  Is the problem that I've declared it twice?

Comment: I've added my own answer because I needed the space.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
String massVal = (String) mass.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

is making you assign the value to a new variable named `massVal`, with a different scope than the previously declared `massVal`.
Switch it to:

```
massVal = (String) mass.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Comment: and you guys are geniuses @Vitor and Justin

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems.

Declaring a class member `massVal` as you've done here is fine.

```
public String massVal;
```

You're then *re-declaring* and *assigning* massVal in an anonymous `OnItemClickListener`.

```
String massVal = (String) mass.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

In the anonymous `OnClickListener` that is giving you this problem, which is in a completely different scope than the anonymous `OnItemClickListener` above it, massVal never gets assigned and is therefore still `null`.

---

Typically a better design is something like this:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    private Button myButton;
    private EditText myEditText;
    private String myString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);

        myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String text = myEditText.getText()
            if (text != null) {
                myString = text.toString();
                // ... continue processing your string
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could up vote you but my reputation is not high enough @Justin.  Thank you so much.  It is working!!  I know I need to read more about it, but when would I use a non anonymous OnClickListener?

Comment: Oh no problems, just glad to help out. In regards to anonymous vs. non-anonymous, it's really up to you. If I've ever got a really simple `onClick` method, I'll use an anonymous class, but if I'm doing some more complicated things, I'll move all the logic into it's own named class. It cleans the code up a lot (Ex. `myButton.setOnClickListener(new MyCustomOnClickListener());`) but can be annoying if you want to do UI stuff with that class (because then you have to pass references to your components).

Comment: So that means that if there is nothing entered in the EditText view the EditText will never be converted to a string (which would have caused a null pointer exception)?

Comment: Yep. You may find code on the 'net that looks like this: `myEditText.getText().toString()`, but if nothing was entered in the `EditText` then `myEditText.getText()` will return null, leaving you with `null.toString()`. I typically separate the operations and check for `null` for safety.

Comment: This is only my second program, the first one is on the Google Play market.  Prior to this I've never programmed anything at all.  This is quite tedious but rewarding.  It's like making the effort to break through concrete with a spoon to find heaven on the other side.  Takes a lot of patience.

Comment: Absolutely. I've gone through a lot of pain too, but the end result is nice. You should pick up a standard intro to Java book. It will really help you understand the concepts of Android and allow you to evolve much faster.

Comment: I've been to the bookstore and I still haven't picked anything up.  I bought a Java programming book a year ago and went through some of it, but I found that it was very difficult to retain unless using it for my specific project.  I'm going to look at it again, and maybe buy one that has more conceptual descriptions.